# Flaw in the proof that $(-1,1)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

This is an answer given by a student. I am totally lost with this solution, could not convince him that this does not work.

He said write $\mathbb{R}$ as $$\bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{R} }r (-1,1).$$

Each $r(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and so is the union over all real numbers except when $r=1$.

So, $$(-1,1)=\mathbb{R}\setminus \bigcup_{r\neq 1} r(-1,1)$$

which implies that $(-1,1)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ being complement of an open set.

How do I convince him that this is wrong justification. I was shocked when I saw this for the first time and still I shock. Could not spend more time on this, so, posting it here.

Comment: What does $r(-1, 1)$ mean? Is it $(-r, r)$?

Comment: @Arthur yes. It means that.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{R}\setminus \bigcup_{r\neq 1} r(-1,1)$ is the empty set.

Comment: I am not sure the second equality is correct

Comment: Why write $r(-1,1)$ instead of $(-r,r)$, out of curiosity?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 no idea...

Comment: @Elvorfirilmathredia You are right.. I should have asked him if $A=B\cup C$ implies $B=A\setminus C$ always.. Thanks...

Comment: @Anaedonist You are right.. I should have asked him if $A=B\cup C$ implies $B=A\setminus C$ always.. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The student thought the same as he added or subtracted numbers. It would be OK, if the sets of the family were pairwise disjoint. Try to convince the student this is not the case.

Comment: You are right.. I should have asked him if $A=B\cup C$ implies $B=A\setminus C$ always.. Thanks...

Comment: In other words, $X=\cup_{a\in A}S_a$ does $not$ imply $ X\setminus  S_{a_1}=\cup_{a\in A \setminus \{a_1\}}S_a\;.$

Answer (score 4):

The equlity from your post is false. Actually$$\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{r\neq1}r(-1,1)=\emptyset$$(which is indeed a closed set).

Comment: You are right.. I should have asked him if $A=B\cup C$ implies $B=A\setminus C$ always.. Thanks...

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw is that your friend seems to have misunderstood what $\bigcup_{r\neq 1} r(-1,1)$ is. To illustrate, let's work with just $r \in \{1, 2, 3\}$. Compare
$$
(-1, 1)\cup (-2, 2)\cup (-3, 3)
$$
to
$$
(-2, 2)\cup (-3, 3)
$$
Do the same with all *possible* real values of $r$ instead of only $3$, and you still get the same effect.

Comment: You are right.. I should have asked him if $A=B\cup C$ implies $B=A\setminus C$ always.. Thanks...